# Extracting data from NetCDF file

Tags: r, netcdf, ncdf4

I'm working in R trying to use the data found here (https://datadryad.org/resource/doi:10.5061/dryad.dk1j0; two top files) to create a table similar to this: [administrative_name, GDP2010, GDP2011....., GDP 2015]

As far as i can see i need to extract the name of the administrative units from the "admin_areas_GDP_HDI.nc" file and combine them with the annual data in the GDP_per_capita_PPP_1990_2015.nc file.

With the ncdf4 package i've managed to open the archives, and to get all the attributes and variables, however I don't know how to access the data and extract it.

I've been trying to access the data all day, but i have limited experience with NetCDF archives, and have not managed to extract the data. Any pointers would help me out!

Answer (score 1):

I like to use the [raster](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/raster/index.html) package for dealing with NetCDF files. It uses the `ncdf4` package to read in the files, but offers some additional tools for processing rasters. You did not mention what data you want to extract, so the example below shows the mean GDP for each administrative unit.

```r
library(raster)

#Read in NetCDF files
ad -> brick('admin_areas_GDP_HDI.nc')
gdp -> brick('GDP_per_capita_PPP_1990_2015_v2.nc')

#Calculate mean GDP using admin zones
zoneMean -> zonal(gdp, ad[[1]], fun='mean', na.rm=T)
```